# Click on a button by Identifying nearby Element

Tags: selenium, uniqueidentifier

Name       Mobile No    Introducer   Created On     Status                   Action

Adill     6666655555        Nitesh        05-02-2014      Pending For Approval     [button]

Adill     6666644444        Nitesh        05-02-2014      Pending For Approval     [button]

the situation is like this,  I want to click on buttons by checking their unique mobile no.  let suppose I want to click on button2 where mobile number is 666644444. So How can I perform this thing ?

enter code here :

```
<tr class="even">
<td class="">Adil Imroz</td>
<td class="">999933333</td>
<td class="">Adil</td>
<td class=" sorting_1">04-02-2014</td>
<td class="">
<span class="undefined">Pending For Approval</span>
</td>
<td class="">
<a id="editCustomerDetails" class="btn btn-info btn-small" onclick="showUpdateForm(2);">
<i class="halflings-icon edit halflings-icon"/>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td class="">Adil Imroz</td>
<td class="">9999444444</td>
<td class="">Adil</td>
<td class=" sorting_1">04-02-2014</td>
<td class="">
<span class="undefined">Pending For Approval</span>
</td>
<td class="">
<a id="editCustomerDetails" class="btn btn-info btn-small" onclick="showUpdateForm(3);">
</td>
```

Comment: xpath will help you achieve it. Give the html for proper answer.

Comment: Xpath for one of the button is like this, ".//[@id='customerTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]" where tr changes with according to the line, I don't want that. I want to achieve this by some other locator

Comment: We will need to reach the button from the mobile numbers, so I will need the whole parts html. You can try it yourself, using findelement within the element for 'mobile number'.